# How to execute the right route? symfony

Tags: backbone.js, symfony

Im using backbone, and i want to save a new model into database with collection.create() method.

I have two routes with the same name /document in Symfony. The two routes have different methods first route for querying for objects and second route for saving objects into database. So how can i specify the route for saving object to database? Is it possible?

Here si my controller, but symfony is creating for me router for documentAction() method and for createAction method. Because when i write in console to see my names of router with php bin/console debug:router i see that it's made by symfony.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use AppBundle\Entity\Document;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


class DocumentQuery extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/doc")
     * @Method({"GET"})
    */
    public function documentAction()
    {
        $id = $this->getUser()->getId();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $documents = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Document')->findAllOrderedById();
    $titles = array();

    foreach($documents as $document) 
    {
        $user_id = $document['user_id'];
        $title = $document['title'];

        if($user_id == $id)
        {
            $titles[] = $document;
        }             
    }

    return new JsonResponse($titles);

    //return new JsonResponse($document);
    //return new JsonResponse($documents);
    //dump(json_encode($documents));
    //return $this->render('default/doc.html.twig', array('documents' => $documents, 'id' => $id));
}

/**
 * @Route("/doc")
 * @Method({"POST"})
*/
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $content = $request->getContent();

    $document = new Document();

    $document->setTitle($request->get('title'));
    //$document->setBody($content);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($document);
    $em->flush();

    return new JsonResponse($document);
}
}
```

Collection:

```
var User = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: DocumentUser,
        url: '/doc',
        initialize: function(){
                this.fetch();
                console.log(this, "this.collection");
        },

});
```

Collection.create:

```
save: function()
        {

                this.collection.create({
                        title: $("#title").val()
                });
                console.log(this.collection);
        }
```

Routing yml. I made it by your posted code:

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

document_query:
    path:     /doc
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Controller:DocumentQuery:documentAction}
    methods: [GET]

document_save:
    path:     /doc
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Controller:DocumentQuery:createAction}
    methods: [POST]
```

[Here is the router, you can see app_documentquery_document and app_documentquery_create is made by symfony, and the document_query and document_save i made in routing.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UuW8.png)

Comment: The same is probably tied to different HTTP methods (`GET` for querying and `POST` for saving). You will need to post your code that defines the routes in Symfony and the code for managing your data in Backbone

Comment: Ok, you routes where good, you can delete what I'd proposed you (in symfony you can use annotations for defining routes or yml, or .xml) and It's fine to have the annotations.

Comment: And how to use annonations? Sorry again for so much questions

Comment: You had the correct annotations in the controller before. You can delete document_query and document_save parts of your router.yml.

Comment: Oh ok. but it will not save me the attribute title of the model to the database. Am i missing something else? If you can help me more.